# How can i disable plugin image in wysiwyg only in my module?

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg

**Hi everyone,**

I want to disable upload images in wysiwyg editor only in my module, how can i do that ?

I'm in magento **2.3.3**

**Button "Insert image.."**
[image]

**Plugin image in toolbar**
[image]

Thankyou !

Answer (score 1):

**In your module add this in your editor :-**

```
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>>
            </item>
       </argument>
```

Comment: Yes, but the button image in toolbar of wysiwyg stay appears, How can i hide it ?

Comment: how you can add this editor in code please add this code